# Magento 2 mixins stopped working

Tags: magento2, javascript, widget, mixins

I want to create a mixin on a third party module (MageWorx OptionFeatures)

This is what i have now.

> app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/base/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'MageWorx_OptionFeatures/js/catalog/product/features': {
                'MyCompany_MyCompany/js/catalog/product/features-mixin' : true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/base/web/js/catalog/product/features-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mageworx.optionFeatures', widget, {
            firstRun: function firstRun(optionConfig, productConfig, base, self) {
                console.log('mageworx.optionFeature mixin');
            },
        });
        return $.mageworx.optionFeatures;
    }
});
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score -2):

Kindly check this

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/mixins/

This is the best guide for you.

Comment: Thank you, but i have already followed this guide. If you see something i have missed, please let me know.